# Designation and explanation in documentation of project

Tags: c++, qt, interaction

My question is about overview of hierarchy of interaction. I am trying to understand one project. which was written by another programmer. See attach.

I am confusing with two things:

1) direction of the arrows (I know in inheritance it should have been pointed to another direction, but here is no inheritance! So could such scheme exist or it is wrong?)

2) marks like "+", "-" and "#" (I have not ever seen such designation, but since nothing is said in the article I read, I am wondering, is it a common explanation or also inaccuracy? )

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Pqg.jpg)

Comment: The top-paper, with the arrows seems to show header-file dependencies, not inheritance. The bottom paper seems to be a standard [Unified Modeling Language (UML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagram.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that

Comment: I've never seen a header-file dependency chart on paper before. But there are tools which can help you create such diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the commends, those notations are of UML language. For your questions:

1) From the first diagram, the arrows do not look like inheritance, but rather dependencies, e.g., `playerwindow` must include `QMainWindow`.

2) The signs like `#`, `+` and `-` are of UML language notations and in that case they denote `protected`, `public` or `private` functions or variables.